# How to create an empty box in Power Math Mode?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, box

I want to create an empty box in power of a number. See attached image for reference.

How can I create a box in math mode?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, depending on the size of the box you want.

[image]

Note that you need `\usepackage{amssymb}` for the `\square` command, and
`\usepackage{graphicx}` for `scalebox`.