Displaying larger squares in math mode for students answering
How to display larger squares/boxes in questions for students to fill in. In particular, I want to increase the size of the squares shown in the figure below. The MWE.
\documentclass[addpoints,16pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
Fill in the blank square
 $$ 6.2 \times 10^{ \square} = 6200 $$

 $$\frac{\square}{100}=0.3$$
\end{document}



Welcome in this community. Do you search a particular package to make it or a math-mode approach?

Unrelated to your question, but please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

(in particular check this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278862/36296)

Other possible solutions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148026/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655844/how-to-create-an-empty-box-in-power-math-mode

Thank you all for the solutions. That was quick. I will go with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148026/36296.

Don't use $$ for displayed maths in LaTeX. LaTeX doesn't support $$. Use \[ ... \] or \begin{equation}...\end{equation} instead!

Defining a command that gives an arbitrary sized \fbox is actually pretty straight forward (arguments have the same meaning as for \rule, so the optional is a vertical offset, first is the width and second is the height):
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mybox[3][0pt]
  {\begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\rule{#2}{0pt}\rule[#1]{0pt}{#3}}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
$10\mathbin{\mybox{10pt}{10pt}}5=5$ % \mathbin for spacing of binary operator

$\mybox[-1pt]{10pt}{10pt}+10=15$
\end{document}

If you want the macro to have a key=value interface instead of two mandatory and an optional argument you can also define something like that (though this will be a bit more complicated). I use expkv-cs (disclaimer: I'm the author of it) for the key=value interface (because it's very straight forward for simple macros with only a handful of keys):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcSplit\mybox
  {
     voff    = 0pt
    ,width   = 1.5ex
    ,height  = 1.5ex
    ,v: text = c_novalue_tl
    ,pad     = 0pt
  }
  {%
    \raisebox{#1}
      {%
        \fboxsep=\dimexpr#5-\fboxrule\relax
        \fbox
          {%
            \IfNoValueTF{#4}
              {%
                \rule{#2}{0pt}%
                \rule{0pt}{#3}%
              }
              {\phantom{#4}}%
          }%
      }%
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\mybox
  {
     meta  size = {height={#1},width={#1}}
    ,alias s    = size
    ,alias h    = height
    ,alias w    = width
  }

\begin{document}
$10\mathbin{\mybox{}}5=5$

$10\mathbin{\mybox{s=2ex,voff=-.3ex}}5=5$

$10\mathbin{\mybox{w=2ex,voff=-.3ex}}5=5$

$\mybox{text=15,pad=1pt}+7=22$
\end{document}


VERSION 1. 1) Can you explain a little the use of \fboxsep=-\fboxrule?  2) Vertical offset of -2pt gives a pretty output.

@projetmbc \fboxsep sets how much whitespace appears between the contents of the box and the inner edge of the surrounding rules. Setting it to the negative of those rules' thickness makes the box exactly as big as specified on the outer edge. In version 2 you can specify whatever defaults you want (though I'd advise to set the vertical offset to use the unit ex, so something like -0.05ex or so).
